# Laravel query builder blank response to table password_resets

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a api in laravel 6 and i have problem with the query builder but only with the table 'password_reset', when im trying to get the email and verify if the token is correct i get blank response but the records match with the request i send.

```
$resets = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$request->email)->get();
```

the same with:

```
$resets = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email',$request->email);
```

also try creating a model PasswordReset and get the data like:

```
$resets = PasswordReset::where('email',$request->email);
```

but still no response.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove the where clause?

Comment: I get a response with all the records

Comment: Then there is no record where the email column matches the value of $request->email. Query Builder is not going to lie to you, please re-check the $request->email value and check that in the email column of the table there is a record that is exactly the $request->email value.

Comment: Sorry, when save the token i put the email in the token field and viceversa